# How to enforce implementation of abstract to behave a certain way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

As best practices, how would one go on about enforcing all implementations to handle exceptions in a specific way. For instance, let's say I have the following interface

```
public interface IApplicationProvider<TData> : IDisposable{ 
    TData Get(string appName); 
}

public abstract ApplicationProviderBase<MyDTO> {
    public abstract MyDTO Get(string appName); 
}

public class SomeApplicationProvider: ApplicationProviderBase {
    public MyDTO Get(string appName){
        ...
        if (somecondition == somecondition)
            throw new InvalidOperation("Application could not be fetched due to a custom error"); 
    }
}
```

In the UI it will handle all "InvalidOperations" and display the message back to the user. However, another approach would be to create a custom object that will wrap the data and any error messages.

```
public OperationObject Get(string appName){
        var operationObject = new OperationObject(); 

        if (somecondition == somecondition)
            operationObject.ErrorMessage = "message"; 
        else
            operationObject.Data = MyDTO
    }
```

Edit: Basically I want a way for all providers to provide a reason why the operation failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I have handle this in the past is by leveraging a simple operation result class. Essentially what you do is wrap your success and failures in an object that holds the status of the operation, any data it returned, and maybe a message describing what happened. Here's a sample

```
public enum OperationStatus { Success, Failure, Pending }
public class OperationResult<T>
{

    public T Data { get; private set; }
    private OperationStatus opStatus;

    public string Status
    {
        get
        {
            return this.opStatus.ToString();
        }

        private set
        {
            var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(OperationStatus));
            if (names.Contains(value))
            {
                this.opStatus = (OperationStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(OperationStatus), value);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Illegal Status Type");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Message { get; private set; }

    public bool IsSuccess
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Status == OperationStatus.Success.ToString();
        }
    }

    public OperationResult(OperationStatus status, string message, T data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
        this.Status = status.ToString();
        this.Message = message;
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(OperationResult<T> result)
    {
        return result.IsSuccess;
    }
}
```

I'll refer you to a blog post that discusses a similar technique for method responses http://www.appvnext.com/blog/2015/12/10/outcome-basics-part-i.

Using such a technique will provide a convention for your providers to communicate any exceptions and also successes.

Comment: I've implemented this approach, and thanks for the blog post.